# Floating Menu that stays within parent div

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a JavaScript menu that I will like to scroll with the user, I have tried to use the top function but that locks the menu to the top of the screen. Is there anyway to have a fixed menu float within a parent div? So once you scroll down it will go to the top of the screen?

You can see the menu here: http://www.jowa-usa.us/jowaabproducts.cfm

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for a sticky sidebar plugin since that will do exactly what you are looking for. [Here's](http://mojotech.github.io/stickymojo/) one that seems pretty good.